# Git : Creating submodules in a branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules

I am new to git so apologies if my terminologies are a bit out of whack.

I have a main repository, a Development branch from the main repository and a test data repository.

I have added test data as a sub module in the main repository so that I can access the contents of test data in my main repository.

Will the sub module added in main be reflected in Development if I pull the changes from Main to Development?

If not, is it possible to add a sub module in a branch or can it be done only at the repository level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the sub module added in main be reflected in Development if I pull the changes from Main to Development?

Yes. When you merge `main` branch to `development` branch all the changes of main will come to development as well.

> is it possible to add a sub module in a branch or can it be done only at the repository level?

`Git` tracks the changes you make in that particular `branch`. Not possible to make repository level changes. If you want that changes to reflect in all the branches, then make the change in the `master` or the main branch which you are using and merge that branch into all the other branches you are working on.

How to merge a branch1 to branch2?
Run the following commands:

1. `git checkout branch1`
2. `git merge branch2`